# Custom Signup/Registration form with Auth0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to use Auth0 for an Application but I need to redirect the user to a registration form/page after they signup though the Auth0 captive page.
Is there any pattern or strategy suggestion regarding this subject?